# Get All Remote Variables in Script Block

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Is there a way to get a list of all remote variables in a script block?

Consider the following:

```
$x = 1
$block = { Write-Host $using:x }
Invoke-Command -Session (New-PSSession) -ScriptBlock $block
```

Inside of $block, is there any way of getting a list of available $using: scoped variables?

```
$x = 1
$block = { Get-Variable }
Invoke-Command -Session (New-PSSession) -ScriptBlock $block
```

Does not yield $x as an available variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

The remote side doesn't know anything about the variables. They get serialized and then the deserialization code and the literal serialized XML is embedded.

If you're the one writing the script bock, then I recommend you just assign each `$Using:` variable to a local variable inside the scriptblock:

```
$block = {
    $x = $Using:x
    $y = $Using:y
}
```

I wrote a more detailed explanation of [how `$Using:` is implemented](https://www.briantist.com/how-to/use-duplicate-dsc-script-resources-in-loop/) on my blog regarding using it in DSC Script resources.